# Uploading Files on production server returns either CORS error or POST 400 Bad Request using Apollo-Graphql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, graphql

I'm having trouble on uploading files to my production server, in a local environment, everything works fine just as expected, but when I try to do a a Mutation containing file uploads (and only on those mutations) it throws me a CORS error. I'm using Spaces to upload the files and save them into my Database.

***app.ts (Back-end):***

```
const configureExpress = async () => {
  const app: express.Application = express();

  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use('/services', servicesRoute);

  const { typeDefs, resolvers } = await buildSchema;
  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    playground: true,
    introspection: true,
    uploads: {
      maxFileSize: 1000000000, 
      maxFiles: 100,
    },
    context: async ({ req }) => ({
      auth: await Auth.getUser(req),
    }),
    formatError: (err) => ({
      message: err.message,
      code: err.extensions && err.extensions.code,
      locations: err.locations,
      path: err.path,
      extensions: err.extensions && err.extensions.exception,
    }),
  });

  server.applyMiddleware({ app });

  return app;
};

export default () => database.connect().then(configureExpress);
```

***client-auth.ts (On the Front-end):***

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors }: any) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    console.log(graphQLErrors);
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message }: any) => console.log(message));

    graphQLErrors.map(({ code }: any) => {
      if (code === 'UNAUTHENTICATED') {
        persistStore(store)
          .purge()
          .then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
      }
      return true;
    });
  }
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = store.getState().auth.user!.token;
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
});

const uploadLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: 'https://api.example.com.br/graphql'
  // uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, authLink, uploadLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: {
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    },
  },
});
```

***resolver.ts***

```
 return propertyModel.create({
      ...data
    } as DocumentType<any>).then(async property => {

    const user = await userModel.findById(input.userId);
    if (!user) throw new UserNotFound();
    await ownerModel.findByIdAndUpdate(user.owner, {
       $push: {
           properties: property.id,
        }
    });

    if (input.images) {
      input.images.forEach(async image => {
        const uploadedImage = await FileS3.upload(image, {
        path: 'images',
        id: propertyId.toHexString(),
        });
        await property.updateOne({$push: {images: uploadedImage}});
      });
    }
    
    if (input.scripture) {
      const uploadedScripture = await FileS3.upload(input.scripture, {
        path: 'documents',
        id: propertyId.toHexString(),
      });
      await property.updateOne({scripture: uploadedScripture});
    }
    if (input.registration) {
      const uploadedRegistration = await FileS3.upload(input.registration, {
        path: 'documents',
        id: propertyId.toHexString(),
      })
      await property.updateOne({
          registration: uploadedRegistration,
      });
    };

    if (input.car) {
      const uploadedCar = await FileS3.upload(input.car, {
        path: 'documents',
        id: propertyId.toHexString(),
      });
      await property.updateOne({
          car: uploadedCar,
      });
    };

    if (input.ccir) {
      const uploadedCcir = await FileS3.upload(input.ccir, {
        path: 'documents',
        id: propertyId.toHexString(),
      });
      await property.updateOne({
        ccir: uploadedCcir,

      });
    };

    if (input.itr) {
      const uploadedItr = await FileS3.upload(input.itr, {
        path: 'documents',
        id: propertyId.toHexString(),
      });
      await property.updateOne({
        itr: uploadedItr, 
      });
    };
      
    if (input.subscription) {
      const uploadedSubscription = await FileS3.upload(input.subscription, {
          path: 'documents',
          id: propertyId.toHexString(),
        });
       await property.updateOne({
          subscription: uploadedSubscription
       });


    return property;
    });
  };
```

I'm really lost regarding this error, is this an actual server error? (Production server is on DigitalOcean in Ubuntu) or something wrong regarding the code?

Comment: The code looks fine. You're saying you get a 400 error or a CORS error. You can't get both at the same time so which one is it?

Comment: I was first getting the CORS error on a mutation in wich I have some file uploads (minimum of 5) after digging through the code and refactoring some of my Mutations, the CORS error was replaced with the 400 Bad Request (note: that this error only throws when I upload a file, all the other queries and mutations work fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any one happens to have this same problem, here's how I solved.
After digging through the code I realized that in the server I was receiving a Maximum call stack size exceeded, upon looking further to this problem I realized that It was an error regarding the Graphql-Upload dependency, I fixed it by removing it as a dependency and added the following on my package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "fs-capacitor":"^6.2.0",
    "graphql-upload": "^11.0.0"
  }
```

after this I just executed this script: `npx npm-force-resolutions`. And It worked all fine.

Answer (score 1):

For CORS, if you are using the latest version of ApolloServer then turn on the CORS:

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  cors: {
      credentials: true,
      origin: true
    },,
  ...
});

//also apply it here
server.applyMiddleware({ app, 
  cors: {
      credentials: true,
      origin: true
    }
});
```

`400` status code is returned for bad request which happens when a client sends a malformed request to server, You need to verify that your client is sending the correct data and headers on via correct HTTP verb (post/get etc)

Comment: Will give this a try, but I'm thinking that this error is somewhat related to my server configurations (On local everything works just fine), and this error only throws when I send a mutation which has file upload on them (uploading them to a DO Spaces

Comment: Production/development environments have difference no matter how similar they are. Also are you using any reverse proxy or is the server listening directly to public api?

Comment: I'm using Nginx, I tried without any proxy, using directly the port in which the API is running, but it didn't work as well. Could this be a Nginx problem? Or is it something misleading in my code?

Comment: @GabrielMoreira as I said earlier, the CORS issue is due to different domains and missing CORS headers. For 400 bad gateway, it can be multiple reasons about which I am not sure

Comment: I'll investigate this further, but I don't think that this is specifically a CORs issue, since all the other mutations and queries work just fine, only in this specific upload file mutation that I receive this error, I'll try some changes and if I manage to fix it I'll come back with a comment.

Comment: @GabrielMoreira you also get a CORS issue for an http status for which you don't respond with that header. E.g if there is an error in your server e.g nginx or nodejs resulting in 500 error, then you ill get CORS error as program breaks before setting the header

Comment: hmm, if that would be the case, then the resolver is actually breaking before it returns anything, hence the CORS error, correct? I'll log the api and see if  I catch anything that could turn into a 500 error

Comment: Exactly Gariel, it can be other than 500 code but point is that code is most probably breaking before the headers can be sat

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, with your help I was actually able to find the exact error and fix it, already posted the solution for it if anyone else happens to the get to this same problem, once again thank you very much!!